# How to clean up big data and reshape it in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, split, reshape, data-cleaning

I have a dataset containing `1-year` data which is sampled for each minute of each day. However, for some days or hours, the number of samples is less than `59 min` (the sensor was turned off). Thus, there is no corresponding time step to it. Additionally, there are some NaN values in the series as well. The data looks like this:

```
        time             x
2019-01-01 00:00:00    10.0    # Day 1
2019-01-01 00:01:00    9.0     # Day 1
... ...
2019-01-01 00:59:00   14.0    # Day 1

... ...
2019-01-02 00:00:00    10.0    # Day 2
2019-01-02 00:01:00    9.0     # Day 2
2019-01-02 00:02:00    NaN     # Day 2
... ...
2019-01-02 00:50:00    14.0    # Day 2
```

As you can see, for Day 1 the data set contains a valid value for each minute during the first hour of the day. The second day has only `50 minutes` for the first hour. Also, there are some Nan Values there.

So my objective is to clean up these data in a rational way and reshape it for further process.

1. if during some hours the sensor was off and has no reading (the time indices are less than 59 min, like Day 2 above), extend the indices to 59 min and indicate the corresponding values as Nan.
2. if more than 80% of values for each hour is Nan, drop that particular hour from the dataset. Otherwise, replace the Nan values with the previous one.
3. reshape the data frame by date-hour on the vertical axis and minutes on the horizontal one. (I need the final data frame to look like this)

   `Date-Hour             min_00 ... min_59`

   `2019-01-01 00:01        10        14`

   `...`

Here is what I have tried so far which doesn't satisfy the above steps completely:

```
df.set_axis(['time', 'x'], axis=1, inplace=True)  # Setting readable name for columns
df.set_index('time', inplace = True) # Setting time column as index
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)  # converting the index to time stamps


# step 1 is needed (but how?) to extend the indices to have all 60 min long 
# even if for some periods there are no data and time index available in data set.


# first of step 2
# if more than 80% of values for each hour is Nan, drop that particular hour 
#  from the dataset, i.e. if more than 12 min (60 min - 80%*60 =12 min) has 
# Nan values, drop that hour. (How?)

# filling all NaN values with their next value (second part of step 2) 
df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True) 

# Step 3 (incomplete)  
# Reshaping the df to Date vs time (hours, minutes)
df.set_index([df.index.date, df.index.time], inplace=True) 
df = df.unstack(level=[1])
# However I want it to be like Date-Hour vs minute  (but how?)

# perhaps it would be easier to apply step 3 before step 2. Because removing 
# the non-sense hours (with more than 48 min NaN) would be easier as each hour 
# appears in a column
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried yourself. It's a lot to process at once. Also it is unclear why ou have to reshape the way you described it in '3.' :-)

Comment: when you read in the data to the dataframe the date part is like `2019-01-01 00:00:00` this or is it like this after you did some date parsing?

Comment: Because at the end I need the data to look like that for another purpose. I edited the Q and added what I have tried. including my wishes ;) @programmar

Comment: The first column of my data is already in that form, so I just needed to set the type as index and date_time (first 3 lines of the added code in the question) @Naveen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took some time to find the correct way to fill missing minutes, as `resample` for irregular start times is a work-around but here it is

```
# necessary stmts for datetime index goes here

a = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='60Min'))

col_list = ['Date-Hour']
for i in range(60):
    col_list.append('min_'+str(i))

new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_list)

for idx, i in enumerate(a):
    if len(i[1])>48: # The 80% from the step-2 hard-coded here
        st = str(i[0])
        nidx = pd.date_range(start=st, end = st[:-5]+'59:00', freq='1T')
        ns = pd.Series(np.nan, index = nidx)
        comb_series = pd.concat([i[1], ns])
        comb_series = comb_series[~comb_series.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
        comb_series.sort_index(inplace=True) #required due to the concat above
        tmp = comb_series['x'].tolist()
        tmp.insert(0,st[:-3])
        new_df.loc[idx] = tmp
```

I guess there's going to be a lot of data, so timing is going to be slow